# Replace JavaScript variable from outside of function

Tags: javascript

I'm not sure if what i am trying to do is possible, or if there's an easier way to do what I'm trying to do.

I have the following code:

```
<script>
function TitleSwitch() {
    var counter = 0,
        fn = function () {
            var array = ['Value1','Value2','Value3'];
            $(document).prop('title', array[counter]);
            counter++;
            counter %= array.length;
        };
        fn();
    return fn;
}
setInterval(TitleSwitch(), 5000);
</script>
```

It rotates the page title between the three variables, Value1, Value2, and Value3 every 5 seconds. This is working fine.

However, on the same page there is some ajax script that is polling for other information related to the app.

What I am trying to do is use some of the data returned from the polling script to change the values in the title switching function.

So, as an example, the poll data may return Value4, Value5, and Value6 instead.

So in the code above, is there any way to replace the values in

```
var array = ['Value1','Value2','Value3'];
```

from another function, outside of the title switching function?

So, say I have a function called pollingDone() that is called each time the polling data is returned, how can I change the values of "array" in TitleSwitch() from within pollingDone() after TitleSwitch() is already running using setInterval?

basically, what I was trying to do is keep TitleSwitch running, but just replace the values used.

The reason I was trying to do it this way is because the titles are switched between the three values every 5 seconds, however the polling script runs every 10 seconds. So if I started the TitleSwitch() function over each time the polling script completes, the third value would never be shown in the title. The first two would show, the polling script would run, and then the titles would start over. So I was hoping to keep the TitleSwitch() function running as-is, and just replace the values it is using.

Comment: I also just updated my question a little to explain why I am trying to do things this way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do that by exposing the `array` in the `fn` function to the outside context.

Here is an example:

```js
function TitleSwitch() {
        var counter = 0;
        this.array = ['Value1','Value2','Value3'];
        var self = this;
        this.fn = function () {
            $(document).prop('title', self.array[counter]);
            console.log(self.array[counter]);
            counter++;
            counter %= self.array.length;
        };
        this.fn();
    }
    var switcher = new TitleSwitch()
    setInterval(switcher.fn, 500);

    function asyncFn(){
      switcher.array[0] = "changed title1";
    }

    setTimeout(asyncFn, 1000)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @Amadan Thanks for the suggestion, I haven't considered that.

Comment: I'm getting: ReferenceError: fn is not defined

Comment: http://jsbin.com/gohaheqabo/edit?html,js,output (with a couple of fixes). EDIT: or that :) But note my suggestion on the position of `%=`...

Comment: Testing it now.

Comment: @SherwinFlight Great. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Pass it in the constructor so you can control the access level from outside.

In the example:

- `myArray` is defined outside the closure that `TitleSwitch` creates.
- When editing its values, the next iteration will use the updated contents.

Like so:

```js
function TitleSwitch(array) {
    var counter = -1,
        fn = function () {
            counter++;
            counter %= array.length;
            // Move to bottom to prevent errors when using a shorter array
            console.log(array[counter]);
        };
        fn();
    return fn;
}

var myArray = ['Value1','Value2','Value3'];

setInterval(TitleSwitch(myArray), 1000);

myArray[1] = "TEST";
myArray[2] = "TEST2";
```

Comment: This will not fulfill OP's objective - he wants to construct the object only once, but change the value later. Think more setter than constructor. Your way works for changing individual elements, but not for assigning a new array.

Comment: @Amadan, I don't really understand what you mean... By passing `myArray` to the outer `TitleSwitch`, it is referenced in the closure that `fn` has access to, which is returned to the `setInterval`. You construct the function once, and you construct the array once.

Comment: Fair enough. I was thinking of the case OP was describing: `array = ['Value4','Value5','Value6']` is not something you can do (but I guess you can get around it with `array.splice(0, array.length, ['Value4','Value5','Value6'])`...)

Comment: Ah I get what you mean now. Fair point; you can't dispose the original array instance in my example.

Answer (score 1):

I think you will have to get your variable out of your function scope, something like this:

```
var titles = ['Value1', 'Value2', 'Value3'];

function TitleSwitch() {
    var counter = 0,
        fn = function () {
            $(document).prop('title', titles[counter]);
            counter++;
            counter %= titles.length;
        };
        fn();
    return fn;
}
setInterval(TitleSwitch(), 5000);

// Here, you can modify your titles in an ajax call
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to replace `array` that is defined as a local variable inside `fn`. If you pull it out to outside of `TitleSwitch`, you can just give it a new value. Alternately, you can use a property on `fn`, or construct a more complex object, to avoid polluting the environment.

You also want to raise the modulo line to the start of `fn`: e.g. if you have a 5-element list with `counter` being `4` and you replace `array` with a 2-element list, your code would break.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var array = ['Value1','Value2','Value3'];
function TitleSwitch() {
    var counter = 0,
        fn = function () {
           
            $(document).prop('title', array[counter]);
          console.log(array[counter]);
            counter++;
            counter %= array.length;
        };
        fn();
    return fn;
}
setInterval(TitleSwitch(), 5000);

function pollingDoneCallback(data){
if(data){
  array=[];
  for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++)
  array.push(data[i]);
 }
}
pollingDoneCallback(['val5','val6']);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Would this replace the values already in the array, or just add to them? I would need to replace them.

Comment: @Sherwin Flight have modified it, to clean the array empty on getting new data